# epydoc warning with @abstractproperry

Tags: python, warnings, decorator, epydoc

I dont what I am missing but the following code:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty

class Abstra(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 77

    @abstractproperty
    def varb(self):
        '''
        returns var
        '''
```

gives the following epydoc error when generating the docs:

```bsh
/test> epydoc -v abstra.py
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| File /test/abstra.py, in abstra.Abstra.varb
|   Warning: Possible mal-formatted field item.
|   Warning: Improper paragraph indentation.
|
```

The warning disappears when I change the `@abstractproperty` decorator to a `@property` decorator. So my question is whether this a bug or I am missing something?

Comment: Is your indentation correct?  The methods should have four spaces in front but they don't.  Not sure if it's just an artifact of cutting and pasting into SO.

Comment: @Binary Phile: indentation has been corrected, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: so..after proper indentation.. what kind of error you are getting with `abstractproperty` that you are not getting after replacing that with `property`?? otherwise.. its problem with your indentation.

Comment: @namit: No warnings at all